# How to get the HBAR balance of an account on Hedera at a specific time in the past?

Tags: rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I can query the current balance from the mirror node using this request:

```bash
curl --request GET \
    'https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/balances?account.id=0.0.3996280' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Based on the documentation found here, for [`/api/v1/balances`](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/rest-api#api-v1-balances).
However, the only query params available for this endpoint are `account.id`, `account.balance`, `account.publickey`, `limit`, and `order`.
Is there an alternative way to do this?

Note: I have thought of a possible alternative way to do this,
using `eth_getBalance` over JSON-RPC instead of the Mirror node APIs, like so:

```bash
curl -X POST \
    --data-raw '{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "eth_getBalance",
        "params":
        [
            "0x7394111093687e9710b7a7aeba3ba0f417c54474",
            "latest"
        ],
        "id": 0
    }'
```

... however, I'm not sure how I would need specify:

- a native-Hedera (non-EVM) address like `0.0.3996280` as the first parameter in `params`
- a block number as the 2nd parameter in `params`, since Hedera does not have blocks AFAICT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are not very clear about this,
but there is indeed a `timestamp` parameter for the `/api/v1/balances` API endpoint.

The [swagger UI for the same `/api/v1/balances` endpoint](https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/docs/#/balances/listAccountBalances) is much clearer about this, defining it as:

> The consensus timestamp in seconds.nanoseconds format with an optional comparison operator

... and it even has several example values with equals, less than, and greater than operators on it.

---

***Example queries***

If you specify a timestamp from **before** when this account was created:

```bash
curl --request GET \
    'https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/balances?account.id=0.0.3996280&timestamp=1083013493.000000000' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

You will get a response showing that it had a zero/ empty balance:

```json
{"timestamp":null,"balances":[],"links":{"next":null}}
```

However, if you specify a timestamp that is from **after** this account was created (and funded):

```bash
curl --request GET \
    'https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/balances?account.id=0.0.3996280&timestamp=1683013493.000000000' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

You will get a response showing that it does indeed have a balance, and the value at the time, of `1000000000000` tinybars, which is equal to 100 HBAR:

```json
{"timestamp":"1683012600.190869000","balances":[{"account":"0.0.3996280","balance":1000000000000,"tokens":[]}],"links":{"next":null}}
```

Hope that helps!